# $\cot \theta = -8/9$, $\cos \theta > 0$ Why does the answer have a positive sin and negative cos but mine doesn't?

Tags: trigonometry

[image: The Question] Question 50
[image: Mathway P1]

[image: MathwayP2]

Mathway Link: https://www.mathway.com/problem/NTcyNjQ2OTM4OA
[image: MathwayP3]

My Work: [image: My work] I understand why it's in quadrant 4 but I don't understand why I got a negative sin and a positive cos. Is there something wrong with the way I drew my triangle?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you drew your triangle wrongly. It should be flipped horizontally, so the right angle lies on the $+x$-axis and one vertex is at the origin.

The answer for $\cos\theta$ presented by the site is wrong, even contradicting its own problem statement. It should have a sign flip.

Comment: Thank you for catching my error! How is it contradicting its own problem statement? Why does the right angle lie on the + X-axis with one vertex at the origin?

Comment: @Padarscha The question says $\cos\theta>0$. The answer says $\cos\theta<0$.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. My second question if you don't mind?

Comment: @Padarscha Ask another question separately please.